# How to bypass the DDOS attack check in particular site in python?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape this site but while getting the data from the site its doing a ddos checkup on me, Which it checks for like 5 seconds and then redirects to the same url but the page opens (On normal browser) but in python i am trying to request the same thing its just returning the ddos check up page. Is there any way i can bypass that or any workaround ?
this is my code :
thanks :)

```
import requests
from urllib2 import build_opener
import time
import json

url = 'https://www.masterani.me/api/anime/63-naruto-shippuuden/detailed'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print page.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a headless browser will work. Use PhantomJS with Selenium webdriver to scrape such sites, or the ones which uses AJAX to load content.

I found these links useful.

https://www.guru99.com/selenium-python.html

https://vocuzi.in/blog/preventing-website-web-scrapers/

Comment: Another useful tool that might work is the dryscrape library.

Answer (score 0):

Anti ddos solutions usually take into account various parameters when inspecting a request's validity. For example, your geographincal location may be a huge factor: When trying to reproduce your issue I'm getting a 200 response, meaning the anti ddos has decided to allow my code to access the site.
I would suggest the using VPN/proxy service such as this [one](https://free-proxy-list.net/web-proxy.html), or, if this is a system destined for production, I would suggest a paid service as these are much more reliable. Notice that some service are robust enough to block many proxy IPs as well